# Laravel 5: $table->timestamps() breaks postgres

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I have a table migrated with `php artisan`. It has timestamps:

```
$table->timestamps();
```

When I seed his table with MYSQL: it's fine. However when I do that with Postgres, I get this error:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "updated_at" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains
```

Is this because I have indexing for my timestamps?

```
$table->index('created_at');
$table->index('updated_at');
```

What can I do? Not use `updated_at` indexing? Define the timestamps as `->nullable();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get makes the solution pretty obvious: make the column `nullable`. You can use the dedicated [`nullableTimestamps`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#adding-columns) method to make it easier:

```
$table->nullableTimestamps();
```